# Upload file as url parameter in php

Tags: php, url, parameters, upload, telegram-bot

I am trying to make a Telegram Bot and it needs to upload a certificate file to it's server (see [enter link description here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook)).

The target url is something like this:

"https://api.telegram.org/bot/setWebhook?url=somewhere/on/the.web&certificate='certFile.cer'"

I need to specify two parameters within a php file. 
1- the url 
2- the file which should be upload.
now as I am new in php I don't know how to send file as a parameter. 
I tried to do it by a html form like this:

```
<form action="https://api.telegram.org/bot########:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/setWebhook" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="url" name="url" value="https://XXXXX.com/send.php"/><br/>
    <input type="file" name="certificate" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="btn" /><br/>
</form>
```

But it doesn't work. 
Any advice will be appreciated.